# Why did Walt still appear handicapped from Hal's perspective after Hal's hypnotherapy?

Tags: plot-explanation, shallow-hal

In the 2001 movie, "Shallow Hal", Hal receives hypnotherapy from Tony Robbins.  This hypnotherapy helps Hal see the inner beauty in people shine through in what society's view of physical beauty is.

Hal starts seeing everyone who has a good heart and is kind natured as physically attractive. (beautiful on the inside)

Hal's friend, Walt volunteers at the hospital and is deemed a great person.  Walt has spina bifida, which causes him to be physically handicapped.  Hal still sees this handicap through his new perspective.

When Hal met the kids at the burn unit, he did not see their burns.

Since Walt had inner beauty, why did Hal still see him as handicapped?

Comment: More a theory than anything, but I'd guess because he's already got that knowledge of him, a sudden change in appearance might lead to some awkward questions.

Comment: Well it's disability vs beauty. There are beautiful disabled people. Here Hal's hypnotherapy makes him see people's goodness in the form of what he considers physical beauty.

Comment: @gabe3886 very interesting. I wish this was posted as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Disability does not mean lack of beauty. There are beautiful disabled people. (Salma Hayek would be hot in a wheel chair for instance :) ). In the movie, Hal's hypnotherapy makes him see people's goodness in the form of what he considers physical beauty. Hence this makes him see physically disabled people with their disability.

Answer (score 2):

Going from the response to my comment, here it is as an answer (but expanded a little).  Still a theory, though:

I'd guess because he's already got that knowledge of him, a sudden change in appearance might lead to some awkward questions.

If you woke up one morning and suddenly someone you've known previously, and know to have a disability was suddenly in the fullest of health with nothing wrong with them, it's going to mess with your head.

Personally I'd wonder if they had always previously made it up; whether I had previously made it up; or if I was still dreaming.  Some might think of it as a miracle and therefore seek the forgiveness of whichever deity they suddenly find an affinity for, but on the whole there will be questions and doubts raised.

Maybe that can be a plot for a future film.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's because he already knew him. Tony Robbins said, from that moment on, he would see people's inner beauty. If not, his friend Mauricio would be hella monsterish with his personality.

Answer (score 1):

Walt still appears disabled because **Hal's hypnosis is not about *ability*, it's about *appearance***.

In other words, Hal has been hypnotized so he is *not seeing ugliness*, which is different than if he was *not seeing disability*. Walt was never ugly to Hal, so Walt looked the same to Hal after the hypnosis.